# Can't find uploaded photos on Google+

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, google-plus-photos

I uploaded my photos on to Google+ via Auto upload. My phone died.

A few weeks later I was able to get a new phone. But now My Google+ account shows no photos. Where did they go?

First phone was a *Motorola Droid Razor,* now I have a *Samsung Galaxy S3.*

Answer (score -1):

There should be a photos app which comes with google+ app. This app contains your uploaded photos.